# iMac hangs when waking up with MAMP running

Tags: macos, imac, sleep-wake, performance, mamp

I recently installed the latest MAMP version on my iMac running Yosemite 10.10.4. MAMP runs fine, used it all day and left it running overnight. Upon waking up the iMac, I have noticed the system is hanging:

1. Websites not opening in Chrome
2. Stopping servers in MAMP doesn't respond
3. Force quit Chrome and tried to restart but doesn't work
4. Opened Safari but it won't open any URL
5. Beach ball appears when hovering over the Wifi icon
6. Restarted Mac but system gets stuck on a black screen with a white, spinning icon as if something is in progress
7. Only way to reuse iMac is through holding the power button and powering back on

I'm relatively new to OSX so not entirely sure where to look and how to diagnose. The only theory I have at the moment is that MAMP is somehow hanging the system (it's the only recent change to the system other than Ruby on Rails and a few other development frameworks installed but I haven't used these in a few days).

Any ideas on where to look or how to diagnose?

Comment: Try rebooting, try looking at the Console in `Applications>Utilities>Console` for errors, try uninstalling MAMP. Try looking at Activity Monitor in ` Applications>Utilities>Activity Monitor` for any apps highlighted red because they are frozen or with high memory or CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question directly, but it is a solution....

I am not a fan of doing dev work on my production Mac.  I also don't see any value in setting up a MAMP server because it will be a very rare occurrence that you get a hosting provider with MAMP setup.  Chances are it will be LAMP and by a very small margin, WAMP.

Why not set up a LAMP box with CentOS in a virtual machine.  [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) would be a good choice for this.  The beauty with this is that when your Mac goes to sleep, it automatically puts the VM into a saved state - meaning when wakes, it is right where it left off.

The other huge benefit is that you can move that VM to other machines where as your MAMP setup, you are pretty much bound to your hardware.

Just a thought....

Comment: I prefer working on a Mac but the reason for MAMP is it gives me access to Apache, mySQL and PHP on my Mac for development purposes. I don't expect my hosting provider to have a MAMP installation - just the AMP part. Perhaps I'm missing something in your suggestion?

Comment: You can have the same dev environment on your Mac in a VM.  I build my Drupal sites on a LAMP box running in VirtualBox.  I can make direct connections to everything including shared folders for directly editing files (NFS) and direct MySQL connections via MySQL workbench.  If I hose anything up, it is limited to my VM and my Mac is untouched.

Comment: One more huge benefit of being in a VM versus on your production box is that you have "snapshots."  I can take a snapshot any point in time prior to upgrading things.  If something goes sideways, I just click on 1 button to revert back to  a saved state.  I don't spend tons of effort trying to make things work again.